# Copied ASP.net web forms project to another server; using clauses are correct, but some static classes are not recognizable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Ok, so I am maintaining some legacy web form web site application.  On old box, the links between the projects are ok and intelisense recognizes the static public classes.  After moving the project to a new and faster development box, web forms do not "see" the utility classes.  E.g.:

AspCommonCode.cs -- project

foobar - website project

While in the codebehind program called webform.aspx.cs I cannot see a common piece of code in AspCommonCode.cs in intelisense and the code does not compile because it cannot find the new static, public method in AspCommonCode.

webform.aspx.cs:

```
    using AspCommonCode;

    string FooBarr = CommonCode.Fooing(true);
```

The new web project DOES not recognize the public static method called Fooing...

I am assuming I have to rebuild something or clear out something.  This exact same thing works on the old box with the old project settings.

Comment: Which folder is AspCommonCode.cs in?

Comment: _"I am assuming I have to rebuild something or clear out something."_ - I would at least rebuild the project, yes. Did you do that? There must be something wrong with the reference to the common library. Does the warning mentioning that issue perhaps get snowed under by the hundreds of other compiler warnings that legacy projects usually carry with them?

Comment: Is the AspCommonCode.cs in a separate project? If it is try building that project 1st before building your website and see if that makes any difference. Otherwise try to copy over the dll from the bin folder of the previous solution to the bin folder of the new one and then try building the solution.

Comment: solution was to just rebuild the .sln file...

Answer (score 0):

solution was to just rebuild the .sln file....